# Extract specific value from the string column of a Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. I have the data out from a plugin which is coming through an excel sheet and I need to extract the values from that column.

```
  Plugin Output

 Country:USA   State: Virginia Address: 23 xys lane  SSN:2345550404  Zip : 22102 City: Fairfax

 Country:India State:Virginia  SSN:2345550401  ZIP:452002  City: Indore
```

I need to search the SSN in each row  and create a new column in the new pandas data frame to create a separate column .

Desired Output :

```
  SSN

 2345550404

 2345550401
```

Answer for Serial Number:

```
def find_serialnumber(x):
  num = re.findall(r'Serial Number:\s*([^\n]+)', x)
  return " ".join(num)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and format the input and expected output (`Ctrl`+`K` to format as code).

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

    def find_number(x):
        num = re.findall(r'(?:SSN_)(\d+)', x)
        return " ".join(num)

    df['SSN'] =df['Output'].apply(lambda x: find_number(x))
```

Also extract function from pandas:

> So \d+ means match 1 or more digits.

```
df['SSN'] = df['Output'].apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'(?:SSN_)(\d+)', x)[0] if re.findall(r'(?:SSN_)(\d+)', x) else x)
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr Zak.  What should I do if the other column in need to find is  Serial Number: 00 DB C0 B1 E3 D5 05 7B 57 BE 3A BB FF D1 62 D6 A7

Comment: You can reuse that function with apply(lambda) - but apply another regex.

Comment: Can you help me with the regex ?

Comment: Yes - tomorrow - for now I sugest search at Google :)

Comment: Really? I Can take look later

Comment: I have posted the regex above.